# Haskell fay install failed

Tags: haskell, cabal, fay

I'm trying to install [fay](http://fay-lang.org/) but src compiling fails with

```
$ cabal install fay
...
Preprocessing executable 'fay' for fay-0.10.1.0...
[ 1 of 14] Compiling Data.List.Extra  ( src/Data/List/Extra.hs, dist/build/fay/fay- tmp/Data/List/Extra.o )
[ 2 of 14] Compiling System.Process.Extra ( src/System/Process/Extra.hs, dist/build/fay/fay-tmp/System/Process/Extra.o )    
...
[13 of 14] Compiling Language.Fay     ( src/Language/Fay.hs, dist/build/fay/fay-tmp/Language/Fay.o )
[14 of 14] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, dist/build/fay/fay-tmp/Main.o )

src/Main.hs:89:55:
Couldn't match expected type `Either ParseError (Maybe String)'
            with actual type `Maybe b0'
Expected type: b0 -> Either ParseError (Maybe String)
  Actual type: b0 -> Maybe b0
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `Just'
In the first argument of `reader', namely `(Just . Just)'

src/Main.hs:96:35:
Couldn't match expected type `Either ParseError a0'
            with actual type `Maybe b0'
Expected type: b0 -> Either ParseError a0
  Actual type: b0 -> Maybe b0
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `Just'
In the first argument of `reader', namely
  `(Just . wordsBy (== ','))'
Failed to install fay-0.10.1.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
fay-0.10.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I don't know is this my mistake or a package problem.

I'm using: arch linux, ghc-7.4.2, cabal-1.16.0.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is definitely a package problem as the dependencies were not specified tightly enough. If a package follows the [Package Versioning Policy](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Package_versioning_policy), if you can satisfy the dependencies, the package should build.

Looking at the fay package description I notice that hardly any dependency has an lower or upper bound. So basically, you’ll have to experiment.

Looking at the code I see that the `reader` mentioned in the error is [Options.Applicative.Builder.reader](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/optparse-applicative/latest/doc/html/Options-Applicative-Builder.html#v:reader). This function has changed the type signature between 0.4.3 and 0.5.0, so try to downgrade [optparse-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) by passing `--constraint "optparse-applicative < 0.5"` to `cabal install`.

Comment: Solved. Thank you. In *.cabal I specified to install optparse-applicative version 0.4.3 and it installed without conflict.

Comment: Just solved the same issue with `yesod-bin-1.2.3.3` by specifying `--constraint "optparse-applicative < 0.6"`. So awesome, thank you!